# how to convert\ load javascript file into a typescript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, converters

I have a javascript file which I need to convert it into a typescript file (.d.ts). When I just rename the file as file.ts, I am getting error ("could not find xxxx") while opening it in visual studio. Are those errors in my code or should I add anything extra to the typescript file ? The file is somewhat complex. Need advice\ help.

Comment: Are you trying to convert the file to a TypeScript file (.ts) or a definition-file (like those DefenitelyTyped provides) that gives you type checking in your other TypeScript-files (.d.ts)?

Comment: I need a definitely typed typescript file (.d.ts).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a JavaScript file to TypeScript, you need to:

1. Add a new empty TypeScript file to your project
2. Copy the JavaScript into the TypeScript file
3. Help the compiler to understand the file by fixing any compilation errors (mostly this will involve adding type information that cannot be inferred)

If you want to use a JavaScript file without converting it, [you need a type definition](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201301/Blog/Complex-TypeScript-Definitions-Made-Easy/). There are detailed instructions on that if you follow the link.